# How to get similar words with regex, like, levendhtein or another method in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a string like this: `I'm too big to forget` in the database and doing a search on that string with LIKE`% I'm too big for%` everything works fine, but when trying to do a search like this `% I'm too big to forget history%` or something like `%I'm too big to really forget%` or `%I'm too big to forget today%` has a return of 0. What do I do to find similar values? I did some research on `levenshtein distance`, but I didn't quite understand if this applies in this context;

what i tried:

```
"SELECT sense FROM table WHERE dialogue LIKE '%$dialogue%'";

"SELECT sense FROM table WHERE dialogue REGEXP '$dialogue'";
```

I've been reading and rereading for about 2 days here on Stack and in other places and I have nothing qualified, if anyone has knowledge about it, I appreciate it.

Comment: Levenshtein distance is great for disregarding typos or UK vs US vs AUS vs etc. spelling differences, but not great for searching for similar text. What you need is a relevancy comparison and in mysql you can get that through fulltext search. See the answer to the duplicate question for details. Please note, there are better algorithms out there, but none of those are implemented within mysql as most rely on pre-trained supervised machine learning models, such as BERT. You would use languages like python, R or C++ for this purpose. Or use dedicated text search products like sphinx.

Comment: @sombrio Interesting, thank you, I'll do some research on